# UITableViewCell behavior in simulator vs. phone

Tags: uitableview

I'm using the 3.1.2 version of the SDK.

I have an app wherein I created a UITableViewCell in IB to display two lines of text per cell.  When I run the app in the iPhone simulator, everything works exactly as expected; however, when I run the exact same code on my phone, the app crashes with the following error in the console:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

My iPhone has the 2.2.1 OS and I'm using the 2.2.1 version of the simulator.  Also, the code works correctly on my other iPhone running the 3.0 OS when I'm using the latest SDK (3.1.3 beta 2).

My assumption, maybe incorrect, is that the code must be fundamentally correct and there is some nuance with the 2.2.1 OS.

Does this make sense?  Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the app on debug mode on device then check if it works. Because I am also facing this problem and this problem does not occur when running in debug mode.